# ¿Cómo hacer responsiva Tag <div> que muestra botones en línea?

Tags: html, css

Cómo puedo hacer para hacer responsiva esta división que muestra tres botones en línea (sin usar bootstrap)?

***El problema es que al cambiar la resolución de la pantalla los botones no se muestran alineados***

Código HTML:

```
  <div aling="center" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="row" aling="center" style="display:inline;text-align:center; margin-left:25%">
            <button class="mainForm__total2" type="button" id="startWebCheckout2" tabindex="7"><b>Pagar con  Paypal</b></button>
            <button class="mainForm__total2" type="button" id="startWebCheckout" tabindex="8"><b>Pagar con otro medio de pago</b></button>
            <button class="mainForm__total2" type="button" id="startWebCheckout3" tabindex="9"><b>Pagar con  Pse</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainForm__total2 {
    width: auto;
    background: #00BEFF;
    border: 1px solid #00BEFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: .3s;
    display: inline;
}

    .mainForm__total2:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #00BEFF
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál quieres que sea el comportamiento de los elementos internos del div?, es decir ¿qué acomodo deben de tener?

Comment: los botones deberian ir bajando de uno en uno y centrandose uno debajo del otro

Comment: por ejemplo en un telefono deberian formar una columna los tres botones, si la pantalla es algo mas grande deberian verse dos botones uno al lado del otro y el tercero debajo centrado...espero sigas mi idea

Comment: la etiqueta `<center> ... </center>` aparece declarada como obsoleta en la mayoría de los manuales, y en la recomendación oficial [W3 Obsolete features](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features). Pero, como los navegadores siguen manteniendo compatibilidad con el pasado, es funcional. Prueba a anidar los buttons dentro de ella. No es una solución elegante, ni recomendada por los Gurus, pero para los que sabemos poco suele ser útil, **mientras buscamos una solución canónica**. El problema es que no están obligados a soportarla en el futuro.

Comment: a css mainForm__total2 agrega el atributo float:left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre en esta edición, de la siguiente forma:

**Parte 1**

- Al `div` que es contenedor le damos un `display: flex;`
- Para distribuir de forma centrada los 3 botones damos un `justify-content: space-around;`

  - Si necesitas que los botones no estén pegados al borde del contenedor, le puedes dar a esta misma etiqueta que tenga un `padding` con un mismo valor para los 4 lados

**Parte 2**

Ahora para lograr que 2 botones estén en la misma fila y el tercero se mueva a la siguiente y quede centrado, podemos hacer:

- Creamos una media query con un intervalo de máximo 768px y un mínimo de 600px (*esto va a depender netamente de como estés maquetando*) para:

  - Usar `flex-wrap` para que cuando uno de los elementos del padre no entre en el mismo renglón, entonces se mueva al siguiente
  - A los contenedores de cada botón le damos un ancho definido y una alineación

**Parte 3**

Ahora para el último acomodo donde los 3 botones quedarán apilados uno encima del otro y centrados, podemos hacer esto:

- Establecemos una medida máxima en la media query
- Usamos ahora `flex-direction: column;`para que la distribución de los elementos quede de arriba hacia abajo

```html
    <style>
      .botonera-lista {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 600px) {
        .botonera-lista {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .botonera-lista--forma {
          text-align: center;
          width: 50%;
        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
        .botonera-lista {
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
        }
        .botonera-lista--forma {
          margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
    
    <section class="botonera-lista">
      <div class="botonera-lista--forma">
        <button class="botonera-lista--forma__boton">
          Forma pago 1
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="botonera-lista--forma">
        <button class="botonera-lista--forma__boton">
          Forma pago 2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="botonera-lista--forma">
        <button class="botonera-lista--forma__boton">
          Forma pago 3
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Con una salida así:

Imagen 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 3:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso no es lo que yo nesecito

Comment: La pregunta es clara hacer responsiva la <div> con los tre botones .... si la pantalla es suficientemente aplia los tre botones  en linea , si es un poco mas pequeña dos en linea centrados y un tercer debajo tambien centrado y por ultimo uno debajo del otro  formando una pila en caso que sea aun mas pequeña la pantalla, siempre todo centrado

Comment: Gracias BetaM... Excelente tu respuesta